# Read Data from ADXL343 Accelerometer using C

Tags: c, accelerometer, i2c, pic

I am trying to read x, y and z values from ADXL343 accelerometer. I am using PIC16 microcontroller. I also have an Arduino board and I can read values fine using Arduino board, but I can't seem to set-up a proper code in C to read the values. I am reading the values using i2c and I am using CCS C compiler. Here is my code:

adxl343.h

```
enum {
  adxl343_IIC_ADDR1 = 0x53 , /* Normal Address */
  adxl343_I2C_WRITE = 0xa6,
  adxl343_I2C_READ  = 0xa7,
};
```

main.h

```
iic_power_enable();
delay_ms(1000);
adxl343_write_reg(adxl343_IIC_ADDR1,adxl343_REG_POWER_CTL,0x08);
delay_ms(2000);

errorReadData=0;
adxl343_t xyz;
int i = 0;
int8 lsb = 0;
int8 msb = 0;
int ack = 0;
i2c_custom_start();
ack = i2c_custom_write(iic_addr | adxl343_I2C_WRITE);
errorReadData+=i2c_ACK != ack;
assert(i2c_ACK == ack);
ack = i2c_custom_write(adxl343_OUT_X_MSB);
errorReadData+=i2c_ACK != ack;
assert(i2c_ACK == ack);
i2c_custom_start();
ack = i2c_custom_write(iic_addr | adxl343_I2C_READ);
errorReadData+=i2c_ACK != ack;
assert(i2c_ACK == ack);

msb = i2c_custom_read(TRUE);
lsb = i2c_custom_read(TRUE);
xyz.x = make16(lsb, msb);
msb = i2c_custom_read(TRUE);
lsb = i2c_custom_read(TRUE);
xyz.y = make16(lsb, msb);
msb = i2c_custom_read(TRUE);
lsb = i2c_custom_read(FALSE); /* End register reading. */
xyz.z = make16(lsb, msb);
i2c_custom_stop();

TRACE1("\r\nZ=%Lu", xyz.z);
TRACE1("\r\nX=%Lu", xyz.x);
TRACE1("\r\nY=%Lu", xyz.y);
```

i2c_custom.h

```
int i2c_custom_read(int ack) {return i2c_read(ack);}
int i2c_custom_write(int8 data) {return i2c_write(data);}
void i2c_custom_stop() {i2c_stop();}
```

Output is always:
X=65535
Y-65535
Z=65535

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: An value of 65535 is the same as the line just sitting high. My guess is that you have a hardware problem since it works on the Arduino and not the PIC. Do you have pull-up resistors on the I2C lines?

Comment: Share also the `make16()` function implementation. Are sure that your I2C connections ok?

Comment: The first step is always to test that you can actually read from the device. Try to read the value from register 0x00, which should contain the device ID.